# JetBrains arrow `->`, `<-` code ligatures do not apply consistently in different environments

Tags: luatex, minted, ligatures

I want to use JetBrains Mono (and its code ligatures) to render `->` as an arrow. However, I get mixed results depending on the monospaced environment I am using. My goal is for this to work in the `minted` environment for `Haskell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}
\begin{document}
texttt:\\
\texttt{-> --> ->> <- <-- <<-\\
=> ==> >=> =>>\\
<= <== <<= <=<\\
<-> <=>} 

verbatim:
\begin{verbatim}
-> --> ->> <- <-- <<-
=> ==> >=> =>>
<= <== <<= <=<
<-> <=> 
\end{verbatim}

minted (Haskell):
\begin{minted}{haskell}
-> --> ->> <- <-- <<-
=> ==> >=> =>>
<= <== <<= <=<
<-> <=> 
\end{minted}

minted (Bash):
\begin{minted}{bash}
-> --> ->> <- <-- <<-
=> ==> >=> =>>
<= <== <<= <=<
<-> <=> 
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

When run, only the `texttt` correctly renders `->` and `<-` (though `->>` is never rendered correctly in any of the environments):

[image: a rendering of the given MWE]

The following changes do not affect the output:

- Replacing the font line with `\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[Contextuals=Alternate]`.
- Adding the package `microtype` together with line `\DisableLigatures[<,>]{encoding=T1,family=tt*}`.

Replacing the font line with `\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[Ligatures=TeX]` results in instances of `>>` being replaced with a guillement "»".

I want the Haskell `minted` environment to render `->` and `<-` as a ligature, and am not sure what steps to attempt next.

Comment: I won't be able to help you, I just find it really strange that `<<-` works and not `->>`. Have you tried other coding fonts with ligatures like Fire Code or [the ones listed on the Fira Code github page](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#alternatives)? If I am stating the obvious, sorry about it.

Comment: I'm suggesting more problems to go after than solutions `:D

Comment: Here's another resource that might help you in your endeavour https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/LaTeX-instructions

Comment: Not an answer, but adding `\makeatletter\def\verbatim@nolig@list{}\makeatother` to your preamble makes the ligatures work in `verbatim` (but not `minted`). Also, the ligature for `->>` renders fine for me with xelatex but not lualatex

Comment: Add `[Renderer=Harfbuzz]` to fix all the ligatures in `\texttt` (and `verbatim` with my comment above). See also my [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/685434/208544) about this

Comment: The exact same ligatures do/don't work with Fira Code so it's probably an issue with minted (or fancyvrb or fvextra), not the font

Answer (score 2):

The characters for which ligatures are disabled in verbatim environments is controlled by `\verbatim@nolig@list`; its default definition is `\do\‘\do\<\do\>\do\,\do\’\do\-`. To allow all ligatures, just clear its definition.

Still, some ligatures do not appear correctly if compiling with lualatex in default Node rendering mode. This is fixed by setting `[Renderer=Harfbuzz]` or compiling with xelatex (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/685434/208544) and [this issue](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/252) on luaotfload's Github page).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]

\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@nolig@list{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
texttt:\\
\texttt{-> --> ->> <- <-- <<-\\
=> ==> >=> =>>\\
<= <== <<= <=<\\
<-> <=>} 

verbatim:
\begin{verbatim}
-> --> ->> <- <-- <<-
=> ==> >=> =>>
<= <== <<= <=<
<-> <=> 
\end{verbatim}

Verbatim (fancyvrb/fvextra):
\begin{Verbatim}
-> --> ->> <- <-- <<-
=> ==> >=> =>>
<= <== <<= <=<
<-> <=> 
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now even though `minted` uses `fancyvrb` to typeset verbatim material, it tokenizes the content in a way that prevents ligatures. From the package author Geoffrey Poore in a [Github issue](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/367) I made:

> This is due to how Pygments does tokenization. For Bash, `|=>` becomes `\PYG{p}{|}\PYG{o}{=}\PYGZgt{}`. For Python, it becomes `\PYG{o}{|=\PYGZgt{}}`. (`\PYGZgt{}` is the Pygments translation of `>`.) Because the characters are split between different tokens for Bash (`\PYG{<token_type>}{<token_text>}`), ligatures won't work.