# Some code ligatures work in xelatex but not lualatex

Tags: fontspec, verbatim, typewriter, ligatures, luaotfload

While looking at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/683184/208544) I noticed that some of the code ligatures from the JetBrains Mono font (freely available from their [website](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/)) worked in xelatex, but not in lualatex. Compare:

##### Xelatex

[image]

##### Lualatex

[image]

##### Source

I had to add some characters to `\verbatim@nolig@list` so that the ligatures didn't appear in verbatim.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/verbatim@nolig@list/after}{\do \|\do \=\do \+\do \~\do \#\do \.\do \/\do \?\do \:\do \[\do \]}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}{rl}
<> & \verb|<>| \\
|=> & \verb!|=>! \\
<=| & \verb!<=|! \\
++ & \verb|++| \\
-> & \verb|->| \\
<- & \verb|<-| \\
<-> & \verb|<->| \\
<!-- & \verb|<!--| \\
\textasciitilde> & \verb|~>| \\ 
<\textasciitilde & \verb|<~| \\
\textasciitilde\textasciitilde> & \verb|~~>| \\
<\textasciitilde\textasciitilde & \verb|<~~| \\
->> & \verb|->>| \\
<<- & \verb|<<-| \\
--> & \verb|-->| \\
<-- & \verb|<--| \\
>-> & \verb|>->| \\
<-< & \verb|<-<| \\
/= & \verb|/=| \\
=> & \verb|=>| \\
<= & \verb|<=| \\
<=> & \verb|<=>| \\
\end{tabular}
\hspace{2cm}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
=>> & \verb|=>>| \\
<<= & \verb|<<=| \\
==> & \verb|==>| \\
<== & \verb|<==| \\
<==> & \verb|<==>| \\
>=> & \verb|>=>| \\
<=< & \verb|<=<| \\
\#\# & \verb|##| \\
\#\#\# & \verb|###| \\
|> & \verb!|>! \\
<| & \verb!<|! \\[0.5ex]
[||] & \verb![||]! \\
:?> & \verb|:?>| \\
::= & \verb|::=| \\
:: & \verb|::| \\
?? & \verb|??| \\
<+> & \verb|<+>| \\
.. & \verb|..| \\
</ & \verb|</| \\
/> & \verb|/>| \\
\#? & \verb|#?| \\
]\# & \verb|]#| 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

With lualatex the ligatures for `<->`, `->>`, `>->`, and `<-<` do not appear correctly. Is this a bug in lualatex (or luaotfload, etc.), or an issue with the font?

Note that adding `[Contextuals=Alternate]` as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547456/208544) seems to make no difference.

Comment: use `Renderer=HarfBuzz`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah very simple, thanks. Is there a general rule (or place where I can find such a rule) for when and when not to use the Harfbuzz renderer?

Comment: well when it works with xelatex but not with lualatex that is the first try. (That is doesn't work in node-mode can be a bug, I didn't try to check. You could open an issue at the luaotfload bug tracker.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Opened an [issue](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/252#issue-1706263014)

Comment: Since I thought Ulrike’s answer was good enough to keep around, I made it a Community Wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer answered in a comment, the first thing to try whenever something works in XeLaTeX and not LuaLaTeX is to load the font with `Renderer=HarfBuzz`.  I don’t have that font to test, but you say it worked for you.

The reason is that, by default, XeTeX uses the HarfBuzz renderer for modern Unicode fonts, and LuaTeX uses its own experimental renderer.  You’ve already reported this to them as a bug.